# Calling exiftool on a huge number of recovered images from photorec

Tags: bash, data-recovery, find, exiftool

I am trying to recover images of the last 20 years from a friend.
She moved all recent files to trash, then emptied the trash.
Those images were lying on the system partition, so photorec found a huge number number of files.

As it is not feasible to filter several 100k images manually, I thought about filtering the recovered images with

```
find ./photorec -type f -size +1M
```

These are still a huge number of files, so any attempt to read them and apply

```
exiftool '-Directory<DateTimeOriginal' -d %Y/%Y_%m_%d {???}
```

to put them into some usable folder structure freezes the computer (also nicely, she organised all files in a similar pattern, and this structure is still alive, just mostly empty)

I tried

- `-print0 | while read ...`
- `find ... -exec` the command
- `find ... -exec bash -c ...` a bash function that would do it

exiftool supports the `-r` option but in this case i get all these small files that are supposedly not needed.

I am now thinking about writing a small script that does it but maybe anybody has an idea how to "throttle the pipe".

Any other idea to recover the folder structure after performing the actions described above on Mac OS with HDD are also very welcome; however: unfortunately she used a commercial tool first and recovered a significant number of files back to the original disk :(

Comment: idk much at all about exiftool other than just to grab info, so I'm no help there, sorry. However, once the trash is emptied you're down to file scavenging tools - at which point it depends what tool & how the recovery was performed. At worst, no directory or file name data will be recovered. At best, the whole lot could be restored to a new drive with zero loss. Recovering to the same disk leaves little hope at all of even the recovered files being fully intact. Whilst the recovery tool is performing its recovery, the regular file system is busy overwiting the data list previously scavenged.

Comment: You might have more hope if it was a 4TB drive with only 1TB used, but if it's a teeny SSD, you can probably forget it.

Comment: You never want to loop or run exiftool once for each file.  See [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).  If running exiftool with the `-r` isn't what you want and `find` will do it, then just pipe the `find` into exiftool while using the [`-@` (Argfile) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ARGFILE).  For example `find <conditions> | exiftool -@ - '-Directory<DateTimeOriginal' -d %Y/%Y_%m_%d`  Based upon [this exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=13107.msg70887#msg70887)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the feedback, it was a 1TB HDD but she doesn't even know if it was full or not ... recovery finds around 300GB media data but a lot of that could also be just temp files

Comment: @StarGeek thanks for the idea, i will try to do it as you suggested!

Comment: Disk Drill has a very good rep for deep digging. I have it here but I've never needed its full services to really give it a hard task to work on, so I can't really say. Small drives &/or FileVault will make the task harder. Please advise your friend of the wonderful world of … backups. Keeping the only copy of any data in a single location is an accident just waiting to happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the tip, i will have a look on it; I am in the process of getting the disk out of the display glued iMac ... from now on she'll have an SSD and 5TB time machine

Comment: You could "throttle the pipe" using `sleep` or something similar `find ... -exec sleep 2 ; exiftool ...` using `;` to combine commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell/5130889